# Dismissing of search bar

Tags: ios, swift, search

I have some problem. I have UITableView and header of tableView is searchController with 1 red view (Inside of this view will be some icon). [image]

After staring of search appears cancel button. [image]

And now I press cancel button and search bar resize to full screen size and red view is disappear. [image]

How to solve this problem?

Here is my headerView class:

```
 lazy var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil).then {
    //return UISearchController().then {
        $0.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        $0.searchBar.placeholder = "Искать по имени"
        $0.searchBar.tintColor = .black
        $0.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        $0.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.appleSystemRegular(15)], for: .normal)
        $0.searchBar.setValue("Отмена", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")

    }

lazy var contentView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
    setupConstrains()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

fileprivate func setupViews() {
    addSubview(contentView)
    addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
}

func setupConstrains() {
    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width - 80, height: 44)
    contentView.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - 65, y: 0, width: 50, height: 44)
}
```

Comment: Have you used constraints to arrange searchBar and redView?

Comment: Nope, i will try now

Comment: You can use UITableViewHeaderFooterView to use constraints properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove searchcontroller and try to search only searchbar delegate.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

}
```